# JS variable split container with draggable divider (other than jquery UI layout)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know an easy way or a package that provides a way to resize two divs based on a draggable divider bar? i.e. I have two stacked divs like this:

```
<div id='top-section' style="height: 50%">
<div id='bottom-section' style="height: 100%">
```

I want a divider bar that allows me to change the first divs height property by dragging it.

I know that the JQuery UI layout plugin is able to do that, but I cannot use it in my project due to compability issues.

Comment: <frameset> allowed this, but i doubt you want that simple... dragging is hard on touch screens, you might want to offer buttons that add/subtract height, just a suggestion...

Comment: you can also use CSS to allow about any practical tag to be resized: http://pagedemos.com/vcb86p32efry/1

Comment: @dandavis do you know if it is possible to style the resize control at the bottom right? Tge default is not touch friendly

Comment: i don't know of any way to style that corner control. not saying it's impossible, but it probably is...